# Hyper-V is there a way to use hyper-v to upgrade all of your guest vm's in a cluster

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v, upgrade, failovercluster, cluster-shared-volumes

Hyper-V is there a way to leverage hyper-v to upgrade all of your guest vm's in a cluster, not the cluster nodes but the vm's on them, like cluster os rolling upgrade. I have allot of vm's with windows 2008 r2 and am looking for the best way to get them all upgraded

Comment: No, not really. Other than creating new VMs and migrating applications/workloads, or taking a snapshot before trying an in-place upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to leverage hyper-v to upgrade all of your guest vm's
>   in a cluster, not the cluster nodes but the vm's on them

No, there isn't.